# Photos won't display horizontally?

Tags: css

i'm trying to get images that im echoing to display inline-block/horizontal but instead whatever i do they are just listing down/vertically. how can i fix this?

here's my code:

```
<div class="profile_photos_area">
    <?php
    $dirname = "./data/photos/".$profile_id."/";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    $ignore = Array("_cover.jpg", "_default.jpg");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore) && preg_match("/\.jpg$/i", $curimg)) {
    echo "<img src='".$dirname.$curimg."' class=\"profile_photos\"><br>\n";
    };
    }     
    ?>
</div>

.profile_photos{
    margin-top:0px;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    width: 170px;
    height: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;

}

.profile_photos_area{
    width:665px;
    height:350px;
    background:#000;
    margin-left:-193px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

Comment: did you try float: left; ?

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML. The PHP here is irrelevant.

Comment: no lol i just added that, it has aligned them horizontally now but also now each photo staggers down about 10px each time

Comment: Um, sorry to break this to you but yes, you are using HTML. Your PHP generates HTML. Post what your PHP generates, not the PHP source.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the html your code generate? Look at the asterisks :

```
echo "<img src='".$dirname.$curimg."' class=\"profile_photos\">******<br>******\n";
```

br. **br**!

It *is* html, and it means... **break line**! Just remove that.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wcVRy/)